# Drupal form won't save with TinyMCE (Firefox only)

Tags: wysiwyg

I have a Drupal form with a TinyMCE (3.5.6) instance on it, this is instantiated via the Wysiwyg module. If I save the form in Firefox, it visually displays an AJAX spinner but nothing happens, the form does not save and leaves me on the form. All other browsers work. I can get it to work 2 different ways but not sure why it works and how to translate that to a permanent fix. I have been going through all the suggestions in http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=18821 but have not been successful yet.

1.) If I unminify the code with http://jsbeautifier.org it works without throwing console errors but JSLint throws tons of lint errors in the code.

2.) If I delete the code below it works,

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="60" name="field_caption[und][0][value]" id="edit-field-caption-und-0-value" class="text-full form-textarea" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"></textarea>it works but with the below error:
```

but throws this error.

```
NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED: Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIDOMHTMLDocument.implementation]
http://loc.dbtv.nbcuni.com/sites/all/libraries/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js?mhcuev
Line 1
```

Here is a video of the issue at hand => https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B47tip0c_KEtY2w1akUtcFZHYUU/edit

Comment: Crosslinking to issue on Drupal.org http://drupal.org/node/1907756

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main fix is linked to in comment #6 of the TinyMCE bugtracker here => http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=3152

The source fix is in comment #4 but that won't help many since you need to have an environment to actually compile TinyMCE.